# How to wait until certain request url loads a certain request headers before proceeding in selenium wire?

Tags: python, webdriver, seleniumwire

Currently when this page loads https://alfagift.id/, a certain java script is run on the client side and an element fingerprint is created on the client side. When I checked in inspect element, the element that I need called fingerprint is loaded first in categories. [example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy0n5.png)

How do I tell chromedriver to wait for that certain request url to load and that certain element fingerprint in the request headers to load first?

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability(
                        "goog:loggingPrefs", {"performance": "ALL", "browser": "ALL"}
                      )
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome((ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://alfagift.id/')

for request in driver.requests:
  hdict = dict(request.headers)
  for header_key in hdict.keys():
    if header_key == "fingerprint":
      fp=hdict['fingerprint']
```

This is my current code and most of the time the fingerprint does not load on the first run.  I've tried using driver.implicitly_wait(10) before the driver get(url), it is the same.